# Vue array changes add or remove using treeview from vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use vuetify and treeview. I want to list object fill with items and nested array in every of them.

```
export interface IExamMenuItem {
id?: number | string;
title: string;
link: string;
children: IExamMenuItem[];
```

}

```
<v-treeview :items="items" item-text="title" item-key="items.id" dense hoverable>
                    <template #prepend="{ item, open }">
                        <v-icon v-if="item.title === 'Амбулаторен лист'">
                            {{ 'home' }}
                        </v-icon>
                        <v-icon v-else-if="!item.name != 'Амбулаторен лист'">
                            {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
                        </v-icon>
                    </template>
                    <template #label="{ item }">
                        <v-list-item
                            v-if="item.children"
                            :key="item.id"
                            style="background-color: beige"
                            :to="item.link"
                            link
                        >
                            {{ item.title }}
                        </v-list-item>
                        <v-list-item v-else :key="item.id" :to="item.link" link>
                            {{ item.title }}
                        </v-list-item>
                    </template>
                </v-treeview>
```

When im trying to add or remove from 'items' i doesnt effect the tree, 'items' are update but not in the tree.

Here is the add method

```
private createReferralEventHandler(id: number | null, typeOfReferral: string | null) {
        if (id != null && typeOfReferral != null) {
            let item: IExamMenuItem = {} as IExamMenuItem;

            const main = this.items.filter(x => x.id === typeOfReferral)[0];
            if (main) {
                item = {
                    id: id,
                    title: `${main.title} №${id}`,
                    link: `/Exam/${typeOfReferral}/Edit/${id}`
                } as IExamMenuItem;

                if (!main.children) {
                    main.children = [];
                }
                this.$set(this.items.filter(x => x.id === typeOfReferral)[0]['children'], main.children.length, item)
                main.children.push(item);

                this.titleOfReferral = item.title;
                this.alertCreate = true;
            }
        }
```

Here is the the delete method

```
private deleteReferralEventHandler(id: number | null, typeOfReferral: string | null) {
        if (id != null) {
            const main = this.items.filter((x) => x.id === typeOfReferral)[0];

            if (main) {
                let remove = main.children.findIndex((i) => i.id === id);
                this.titleOfReferral = main.children.filter((i) => i.id === id)[0].title;

                main.children.splice(remove, 1);

                this.alertDelete = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-assign `items` value to force vue to re-render the tree.
Should use something like this to remove an item:

```
this.items = this.items.filter((x) => x.id !== idToRemove)
```

And something like this to add an item:

```
this.items = [...this.items, newItem]
```

Comment: I wrong somehere and i dont know where. Here is exact code https://codepen.io/niko9312/pen/OJRZvOP if you can help i will be very thankful. May be its object with nested array and i modify the inner array